# Spring roo project is not getting created

Tags: spring-roo

Spring roo project is not getting created in my workspace, i have set the environment variables for roo-1.2.3.Once i click finish button after entering project name,top level package,it hangs up and the project folder is created in directory but not in the sts workspace. Anybody please help me with this. I am using sts 3.1.0 and roo 1.2.3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try latest versions, Roo 1.2.4 and STS 3.8.2 or 4.3.1

Comment: STS 3.8.2 includes Roo, try with default included Roo .. it should work

Comment: i am trying with the same Roo which has come with sts 3.8.2 but not working.

Comment: Try with petclinic, open Roo and intro this command only "script --file clinic.roo"

Comment: "script --file samples/clinic.roo" this command also not getting executed.But i found one solution that is, by creating new user login for the system and opening sts there my problem solved temporarily but again the same problem appeared after creating 2 more projects in the workspace.

Comment: It seems a problem on your side. A new user login could means the classpath is different, or the JDK is different, ... check those

Comment: my class path is ;.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar and java home is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07 and while i run roo.bat file there are whole list of errors with apache felix.

Comment: Issue resolved by deleting the ~/.spring_roo_pgp.bpg which was in C:\Users\admin2.